# What if memory is not allocated to '\0' in char array and char pointer

Tags: c

The following two programs are almost similar. In the two programs, memory is not allocated for null(`'\0'`) character.

**Ex A:**

```
void main()
{
        char *ptr;
        ptr = (char *)malloc(2);
        strcpy(ptr, "ls");
        printf("%s\n",ptr);
        system(ptr);
        free(ptr);
}
```

**Ex B:**

```
void main()
{
        char ptr[2] = "ls"; 
        system(ptr);
}
```

1.The first program(Ex. A) is working But i have seen error only with valgrind tool.

**output**

```
[root@localhost tmp]# valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out 
==8619== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8619== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8619== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8619== Command: ./a.out
==8619== 
==8619== Invalid write of size 1
==8619==    at 0x400635: main (in /home/gen4linux/Projects/Cprgm/tmp/a.out)
==8619==  Address 0x51f2042 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==8619==    at 0x4C29C4F: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8619==    by 0x400627: main (in /home/gen4linux/Projects/Cprgm/tmp/a.out)
==8619== 
==8619== Invalid read of size 1
==8619==    at 0x4C2CC14: strlen (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8619==    by 0x4EA4D3B: puts (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==8619==    by 0x400644: main (in /home/gen4linux/Projects/Cprgm/tmp/a.out)
==8619==  Address 0x51f2042 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==8619==    at 0x4C29C4F: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8619==    by 0x400627: main (in /home/gen4linux/Projects/Cprgm/tmp/a.out)
==8619== 
ls
==8620== Syscall param execve(argv[i]) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==8620==    at 0x4EF9537: execve (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==8620==    by 0x4E77D18: do_system (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==8620==    by 0x400650: main (in /home/gen4linux/Projects/Cprgm/tmp/a.out)
==8620==  Address 0x51f2042 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2 alloc'd
==8620==    at 0x4C29C4F: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8620==    by 0x400627: main (in /home/gen4linux/Projects/Cprgm/tmp/a.out)
==8620== 
a.out  test37.c
==8619== 
==8619== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8619==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8619==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 2 bytes allocated
==8619== 
==8619== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8619== 
==8619== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8619== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

2.But the second one is not working

**Ex B**

```
[root@localhost Cprgm]# ./a.out 
sh: $'ls%\211\376\177': command not found
```

Why this happens?

Comment: both are undefined behaviour. Which means anything can happen and it does not have to be consistent.

Comment: This is a side note: (char *) typecast is not needed with `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** both the codes cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

- **In first case**

  ```
  ptr = (char *)malloc(2);
  strcpy(ptr, "ls");
  ```

  you're off-by-one, as mentioned in `C11`, chapter §7.24.2.3,

  > The `strcpy` function copies the string pointed to by `s2` **(including the terminating null
  >   character)** into the array pointed to by `s1`.

  So, the *size* of `s1` should at least be `strlen(s2)+ 1`.
- **In second case**

  ```
  char ptr[2] = "ls";
  ```

  `ptr` does not have a null-terminator which in essence, causes out of bound access which again causes UB.

  Related, quoting the [POSIX manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3p.html),

  > [...] If `command` is
  >      not a null pointer, the `system()` function shall pass **the string
  >      pointed to by `command`** to that command processor to be executed in an
  >      implementation-defined manner; [...]

  A `char` array, without a null-terminator in place, is ***not considered a string***.

---

Having said that, there are a few sggestions,

- For a hosted environment, `void main()` should at least be `int main(void)` to conform to the standard.
- [See this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 0):

The array that you used in Ex B is only of length 2. whenever you store a string in a array `"ls"` automatically a null character is added with is '\0' so "ls" will become `l s \0` when it is stored in memory. Most of the algorithm are based on this NULL character to find the length of string of value of string.

So just declare your array of length 3 and you will be good to go.

Thanks.

Comment: BTW: it's `NUL` and not `NULL`, these two are very different things.

Comment: Thank u. I know the difference. I have mentioned "character" after it. which is \0. If I could have just said NULL and not NUL then it wold have created confusion. which is pointer and which is character

Answer (score -1):

In the first case:

```
ptr = (char *)malloc(2);
```

memory is allocated for two bytes but strcpy stored 3 bytes at this location. So it is basically a memory corruption case but still "ls" command with \0 at the end is stored at the location which makes system command to work.

In the second case:

```
char ptr[2] = "ls";
```

This assignment itself is wrong and is not supposed to work. Behaviour is undefined.

Comment: What you cite as second case **is** defined, it initializes the char array to [l,s] (without `\0`), it is **not** an assignment. UB occurs later when using this array as a string, because the terminating `\0` is missing.

Comment: `This assignment itself is wrong`... -1, my downvote.